# How to insert an item into an existing ListView in order? (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a ListView that is bound to a ObservableCollection (as ItemsSource). It basically b list of string names that I have in alphabetical order.

I would like to know how to insert a single item (string) into the collection and have it automatically sorted, without having to resort the entire list.

Also, is there a way to keep the current ListViewItem selected when performing such a task? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want [AdvancedCollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/helpers/advancedcollectionview)

> The AdvancedCollectionView is a collection view implementation that
>   support filtering, sorting and incremental loading. It's meant to be
>   used in a viewmodel.

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI;

// Grab a sample type
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Set up the original list with a few sample items
var oc = new ObservableCollection<Person>
{
    new Person { Name = "Staff" },
    new Person { Name = "42" },
    new Person { Name = "Swan" },
    new Person { Name = "Orchid" },
    ...
};

// Set up the AdvancedCollectionView with live shaping enabled to filter and sort the original list
var acv = new AdvancedCollectionView(oc, true);

// Let's filter out the integers
int nul;
acv.Filter = x => !int.TryParse(((Person)x).Name, out nul);

// And sort ascending by the property "Name"
acv.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", SortDirection.Ascending));

// Let's add a Person to the observable collection
var person = new Person { Name = "Aardvark" };
oc.Add(person);

// Our added person is now at the top of the list, but if we rename this person, we can trigger a re-sort
person.Name = "Zaphod"; // Now a re-sort is triggered and person will be last in the list

// AdvancedCollectionView can be bound to anything that uses collections. 
YourListView.ItemsSource = acv;
```